# How to make my bot send a message to a certain channel in my Discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to send a message to a certain channel in my discord server.

So I would like to run a command like `-announce [my message here]` and it would send it to a channel in my server called `Announcements`.

I have already tried something like this `return message.channels.get("336313710106902529").send(announceembed)` but it just gives me an error in my console.

`    const msg = message.content
    const announcechannel = bot.channels.get("336313710106902529");

```
if(cmd === `${prefix}announce`){
    let announceembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(":flag_jp: **Announcement** :flag_jp:")
    .setDescription(msg)
    .setColor("#ff0000");

    return message.channels.get("336313710106902529").send(announceembed)

}
```

`

My expected result is for my bot to send a message to the announce channel.
Except it gives me the following error:

````
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\index.js:65:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\craig\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio Code\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:409:14)
(node:896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: You did not copy the actual error, you only copied the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

[`<Message>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has no `channels` property, only `channel` which is the channel the message came from.

What you are looking for is [`<Client>.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) that you would use like so:

```
const msg = message.content; 
const announceChannel = bot.channels.get("336313710106902529");

if(cmd === `${prefix}announce`){
    let announceEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(":flag_jp: **Announcement** :flag_jp:")
    .setDescription(msg)
    .setColor("#ff0000");

    return announceChannel.send(announceEmbed);
}
```